# Android - Application with multiple ListActivity resulting in correct Id in onListItemClick

Tags: android, listactivity

I'm writing an android app which has 2 ListActivity.

ListActivity 1 -> OnItemClick -> opens the details page correctly
ListActivity 1 -> Menu Option -> Opens ListActivity 2
ListActivity 2 -> OnItemClick -> **Should Open** details of the list item of ListActivity 2

**However the 'id' that I get in the onListItemClick of the second list activity is incorrect.**

ListActivity 1 onListItemClick handler:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

Intent c = new Intent(this, ADisplay.class);
c.putExtra(ABDbAdapter.A_FIELD_ID, id);
startActivityForResult(c, ACTIVITY_DISPLAY);
}
```

ListActivity 2 onListItemClick handler:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

Intent c = new Intent(this, TDisplay.class);
c.putExtra(ABDbAdapter.T_FIELD_ID, id);
startActivityForResult(c, ACTIVITY_DISPLAY);
}
```

ListActivity 1 has data from table 1 with primary key "_id"
ListActivity 2 has data from table 2 with primary key "_id".  Could this be the issue?

Comment: what `id` do you get when you clicked on list2....

Comment: How are you creating your lists?  Cursor?  Array?

Comment: I'm getting different values, not sure what the value is.
I'm using SimpleCursorAdapter to create the list

Comment: I think we need to see the full (relevant) code for the second list and the detail class for the second list, otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Barak, the issue has been resolved. See my comments below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.  The second listactivity was created by fetching data from tables with join. Both tables had _id field & the select used was 'Select *' instead of 'Select '. This resulted in the id of the first table being returned though I was expecting the id from the second table.

Corrected the join statement and the issue is resolved.

Thanks [BBdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626122/bbdev) & [Barak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105376/barak) for responding